# Why Picker in SwiftUI works just one time

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, picker

I'm starting with SwiftUI and created this code

```
struct ContentView: View {

let countries = ["CZ","SK","DE"]
@State private var country = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            Form {
                Picker("Pick a country", selection: $country) {
                    ForEach(0..<countries.count) { index in
                        Text(self.countries[index])
                    }
                }
                Text(countries[country])
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("UNECE Data")
    }
}
}
```

if I select value from the Picker it properly returns value back to the Text but if I do the same action again list of values is not shown and XCode writes this to console window

> TableView Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
>   visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
>   (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
>   window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
>   load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
>   bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
>   will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
>   passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window.

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is known bug, on real device it works. Not only you are annoying ...

In your case (to be able to continue) your development, just click on "Settings", next go back and the picker is ready again. By the way, try to click on "Settings", go back and try it again. The link "Settings" has the same wrong behavior.

Try Master / Detail template from apple, add only one Date and check, that it will work the same way. How it is possible? Swift runtime is not part of application anymore (due to ABI)

It works on real devices from 13.3, last SDK on current Xcode is still 13.2. (check your project settings)

Using different Picker style could help.

Comment: Yes, if I move Picker from the Form and use it as spinning wheel this will work fine.

Comment: Dawy, there is still the trouble with "Settings" link. Before you had two links there, so by simple click to another one give you a chance to continue the app in the simulator.  Now you have one only .... Try what i sad, click Settings, go back, click it again ... Don't worry about this bug,l it is really only temporarily ... And finally it doesn't make any trouble on real device.

Comment: it is not Picker bug! it is NavigationView which makes a trouble :-)

Comment: If I combine click on Settings with click on Picker it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug introduced in iOS 13, which apparently only affects physical devices. Update your iOS system to 13.3, it will work well on the real iPhone, but the warning still there

Comment: Actually I don`t run the code on physical device but on XCode simulator. I have macOS and XCode updated to the latest greatest versions.

Comment: dear down-voters, don't down vote the answer, just because you don't like it. What he answers, is TRUE! There is a workaround for NavigationLink where you can activate the link programmatically, for Picker it is not so easy ... and finally not simple solution exists.