# SwiftUI picker greyed out and disabled following selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Using a picker embedded in a Form and NavigationView, I can use the picker to select an item once, but tapping it subsequently causes it to grey out. Following is my code in `ContentView.swift`.

```swift
 var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedType, label: Text("Type")) {
                        ForEach(0..<types.count) {
                            Text(self.types[$0])
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    TextField("Author", text: $quotee)
                    TextField("Quote", text: $content)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

[Screenshot of issue in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhsBi.png)

On the second tap (the one which greys it out), the following error is logged in the console:

> 2020-03-07 17:18:13.037229+0800 Quotable[5645:286914] [TableView]
>   Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells
>   and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view
>   or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may
>   cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform
>   layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait
>   collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also
>   cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes.
>   Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window. Table view:
>   <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView:
>   0x7ffe2f9ab000; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 414 842);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0,
>   -108}; contentSize: {414, 249.66666666666671}; adjustedContentInset: {108, 0, 34, 0}; dataSource:
>   <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c69da4419ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___:
>   0x7ffe2ece5420>>

I can't test this on a physical device, so I don't know if this is just a Simulator issue.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029218/why-picker-in-swiftui-works-just-one-time/60030004#60030004

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029510/1780632 here is the answer ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Picker in SwiftUI works just one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029218/why-picker-in-swiftui-works-just-one-time)

Comment: thanks @user3441734. I suppose there's no workaround for the simulator?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find anything. Apple knows about. We need to be patient

Comment: For me Picker is enabled, when I gave picker style modifier.